# Encoding com.sun.net.httpserver

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a problem character encoding with the library: **com.sun.net.httpserver**

The JVM is configured for the UTF-8 encoding character:

System.getProperty ("file.encoding") = UTF-8

Charset.defaultCharset () = UTF-8

java.nio = UTF-8

When I tried parse Multiform/Data content I discovered that default encoding is: "ISO-8859-1" not UTF-8. I we tried convert InputStream > byte array > String using UTF-8 i received a differente length data between byte array and string content. And only works with "ISO-8859-1"

Example code:

```
public HashMap<String, HttpFormData> getMultipartFormData() {

       //this function return the value of BOUNDARY.
        String boundary = this.getContentTypeBoundary();

        if (boundary == null || boundary.length() == 0) {

            return this.hMultiPart;
        }

        String data;
        try {

            //This function convert InputStream content to ByteArray     
            byte ba[] = this.getRequestBodyAsByte();

            //Only this encode works:
            String cs = "ISO-8859-1";

            data = new String(ba, cs);

            System.out.println(ba.length + " - " + data.length();


            if (data.length() != ba.length) {

                data = new String(ba, "UTF-8");
                if (data.length() != ba.length) {
                    return this.hMultiPart;
                }

                cs = "UTF-8";
            }

            boundary = "--" + boundary + "\\r\\n";

            String sep[] = data.split(boundary);

            String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            for (int i = 0; i < sep.length; i++) {

                Net.HTTP.Server.HttpFormData form = new Net.HTTP.Server.HttpFormData();
                String sep1[] = sep[i].split("\\r\\n");

                String content = "";

                for (int x = 0; x < sep1.length; x++) {

                    String s = sep1[x].trim();

                    if (s.startsWith("Content-Disposition")) {
                        form.contentDisposition = s;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (s.startsWith("Content-Type")) {
                        form.contentType = s;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (s.startsWith("Content-Transfer-Encoding")) {
                        form.contentTransferEncoding = s;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (x != 0 && form.contentDisposition.length() != 0 && form.contentType.length() != 0) {
                        String contentData;
                        if (content.length() == 0 && sep1[x].length() == 0) {
                            contentData = "";
                        } else {
                            contentData = sep1[x] + ls; //"\\r\\n";
                        }

                        content += contentData;

                    }

                }

                if (content.length() != 0) {

                    form.data = content.getBytes(cs);

                    form.parse();

                    form.charset = cs;
                    if (form.name.length() != 0) {
                        this.hMultiPart.put(form.name, form);
                    }

                }

            }

            //System.out.println("readed=" + count);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this.hMultiPart;
    }
```

Client HTML Upload example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8000/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you configured the HTML side to actually *send* data in UTF-8? You've just configured the receiving side.

Comment: Yes Sure, i added the charset UTF-8

Comment: Add the HTML code too, that's what matters.

Comment: i added the HTML client side example.

Comment: And finally, what encoding is the file in that you're sending?

Comment: I created a simple TXT file Encode with UTF-8

Comment: So you've got everything set up as `UTF8`, but you magically get `ISO-8859-1` data? I'd double check everything if I were you. Then triple check. Then get an exorcist.

Comment: i am working and working ago 5 days with this problem. :)

Comment: Are you really sure the file is in UTF8? Have you checked it with a hex editor?

Comment: Yes 100% sure.!

Comment: You're not the first one to say he's 100% sure, and it turns out that he was wrong. Explain how you know that the file is in UTF8.

Comment: When you save the file txt with notepad you have the option select the encode.

Comment: The idea is resolve if from server side. If customer send UTF-8 or other charset via web or software the server side should be encoding and decoding accorded with the local configuration.

Comment: You need to know the charset to decode it properly. If the client sends you UTF8 data, you decode it as UTF8, if the client sends you in another encoding, you decode it as that. It's **not** automatic and it never can be. You should check your file with a hex editor to see it really is in UTF8, and that you're actually sending that file.

Comment: Thanks... I resolved it using CommonFileUpload.